# Compare Nested List Items in a Pair in Python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a nested list like this :

```
[['Asan', '20180418', 'A', '17935.00'],
 ['Asan', '20180417', 'B', '17948.00'],
 ['Asan', '20180416', 'C', '17979.00'],
 ['Asan', '20180416', 'D', '17816.00'],
 .
 .
 .
 .
 ['Asan', '20180415', 'N', '18027.00']]
```

I need to do some calculations for the 3rd element in every list with the one before it, an example :

```
if (A/B) > 0.05: ....
if (B/C) > 0.05: ....
if (C/D) > 0.05: ....
.
.
if (N-1/N) == 1: ....
```

and if the condition is not met, I pop that list.

How can I approach this and what is the most pythonic and fastest way to do it.

EDIT :
let me clarify :
A and B and so on are FLOATS, I just name them A, B,... for better understanding.
the if statements are supposed to find if the A is how much greater than the previous float B.

Comment: How are the values named by A, B etc. stored? `if (A/B) == 1` seems to mean `if A == B`. Is that so?

Comment: What is `A/B === 1`?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson no, they are not the same, i edited my question to a more relevant format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) makes things easy here for pair-wise comparison:

```
l = [['Asan', '20180418', 'A', '17935.00'],
     ['Asan', '20180417', 'B', '17948.00'],
     ['Asan', '20180416', 'C', '17979.00'],
     ['Asan', '20180416', 'C', '200.00'],
     ['Asan', '20180416', 'D', '17816.00']]

new_list = []

for x, y in zip(l, l[1:]):
    if x[2] == y[2]:
        new_list.extend([x, y])

print(new_list)
# [['Asan', '20180416', 'C', '17979.00'],
#  ['Asan', '20180416', 'C', '200.00']]
```

**EDIT**:

If `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`.. are `float`s, then to check for condition you required, you could replace the condition in the above example. And do whatever if that condition is satisfied.

Comment: thank you very much, I did know about zip, but I didn't think of using it this way. your solution solved my problem. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
l = [['Asan', '20180418', 'A', '17935.00'],
     ['Asan', '20180417', 'B', '17948.00'],
     ['Asan', '20180416', 'C', '17979.00'],
     ['Asan', '20180416', 'C', '200.00'],
     ['Asan', '20180416', 'D', '17816.00']]

last_seen = l[0]
new_list = []

for r in l[1:]:
    if r[2] == last_seen[2]:
        new_list.append(last_seen)
        new_list.append(r)
    last_seen = r


print(new_list)
```

Which gives:

```
[['Asan', '20180416', 'C', '17979.00'], ['Asan', '20180416', 'C', '200.00']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to test your condition for every element in the top list, you will need to iterate it.

Since the condition can not be computed for the first element (no 'before' element) we can start at index 1 instead of 0.

The 3rd element in the sublists can be referenced by it's index.
We can get the sublist before the sublist we look at right now by decreasing the index.

Because of the loop, it will not be very fast, but the most pythonic way would be a oneline loop.

```
new_list = [l[i] for i in range(1, len(l)) if float(l[i][3])/float(l[i-1][3]) > 0.05]
#new_list = [['Asan', '20180417', 'B', '17948.00'], ['Asan', '20180416', 'C', '17979.00'], ['Asan', '20180416', 'D', '17816.00']]
```

Because of readability, I would go with a multi line for loop.

```
new_list = []
for i in range(1, len(l)):
    if float(l[i][3])/float(l[i-1][3]) > 0.05:
       new_list.append(l[i])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i][2] <Operator> l[i + 1][2] <Condtion> exp/value:
        Do something here
```

Comment: What happens when `i == len(l) - 1`?